# SQL sums grouped by either column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to solve the following problem using PostgreSQL, with no luck so far.
I have a table `transfers` listing money transfers by account numbers:

```
id | sender | receiver | sum
-----------------------------
1  | 1234   | 2345     | 5.0
2  | 1234   | 9873     | 5.0
3  | 2345   | 7890     | 12.0
4  | 9873   | 7890     | 1.0
```

And one named `accounts`, containing accounts with their owners' info:

```
account | owner_name
---------------------
1234    | Fred
2345    | Wilma
9873    | Barney
7890    | Betty
```

Using PostgreSQL, as a result, I need a table of names of users with a total volume of money transfers (any direction) equal or above a given threshold (say 10.0), sorted by `owner_name`.
i.e. Fred, owner of the account no. 1234 has sent 5.0 and received 5.0, so the total is 10.0. Wilma (account 2345) received 5.0 and sent 12.0. Barney Received 5.0 and sent 1.0, so his total is 6.0. Lastly, Betty sent nothing, but received 13.0. Three users: Fred, Wilma and Betty have their total >= 10.0, so their names should be returned in alphabetical order and we should receive something like this:

```
result
-------
Betty
Fred
Wilma
```

Can it be done in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot with a lateral join and then aggregate:

```
select v.account, sum(t.sum) as overall
from transfers cross join lateral
     (values (sender), (receiver)
     ) v(account) join
     accounts a
     on a.account = v.account
group by v.account
having sum(t.sum) >= 10.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all to get a dataset for all of the transactions including both senders and receivers, and then for the ones that have sum(sum)>10, find the name of the account.

```
select 
  (select account a from accounts where a.account=p.id) as name
from (
select sender as p, sum
from transfers
union all
select receiver as p, sum
) 
group by p
having sum(sum)>10
```